# How does CreateStdDispatch know what method to invoke?

Tags: winapi, com, native-code, idispatch

i'm faced with implementing an [`IDispatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221608.aspx) interface. There are four methods, and fortunately 3 of them are easy:

```
function TIEEventsSink.GetTypeInfoCount(...): HResult;
{
   Result := E_NOTIMPL;
}

function TIEEventsSink.GetTypeInfo(...): HResult;
{
   Result := E_NOTIMPL;
}

function TIEEventsSink.GetIDsOfNames(...): HResult;
{
   Result := E_NOTIMPL;
}
```

It's the last method, `Invoke` that is difficult. Here i am faced with having to actually case the **DispID**, and call my appropriate method; unmarhsalling parameters from a variant array.

```
function Invoke(  
  dispIdMember: DISPID;
  riid: REFIID;
  lcid: LCID;
  wFlags: WORD;
  var pDispParams: DISPPARAMS;
  var pVarResult: VARIANT;
  var pExcepInfo: EXCEPINFO;
  var puArgErr: DWORD
): HRESULT;
```

Not wanting to have to write all the tedious boilerplate code, that i'm sure will have bugs, i went googling - rather than doing any work.

i found this snippit on [the MSDN Documentation of `IDispatch.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221479.aspx):

> Generally, you should not implement **Invoke** directly.

Excellent! i didn't want to implement it anyway! Continuing reading:

> Instead, use the dispatch interface to create functions [CreateStdDispatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221135.aspx) and [DispInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221366.aspx). For details, refer to [CreateStdDispatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221135.aspx), [DispInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221366.aspx), [Creating the IDispatch Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221063.aspx) and [Exposing ActiveX Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221669.aspx).

The [Creating the IDispatch Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221063.aspx) link says:

> You can implement IDispatch by any of the following means:
>
> - [snip]
> - Calling the [CreateStdDispatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221135.aspx) function. This approach is the simplest, but it does not provide for rich error handling or multiple national languages.
> - [snip]

Excellent, [CreateStdDispatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221135.aspx) it is:

> Creates a standard implementation of the IDispatch interface through a single function call. This simplifies exposing objects through Automation.
>
> ```
> HRESULT CreateStdDispatch(  
>   IUnknown FAR*  punkOuter,        
>   void FAR*  pvThis,               
>   ITypeInfo FAR*  ptinfo,          
>   IUnknown FAR* FAR* ppunkStdDisp  
> );
> ```

i was going to call it as:

```
CreateStdDispatch(
    myUnk,          //Pointer to the object's IUnknown implementation.
    anotherObject,  //Pointer to the object to expose.
    nil             //Pointer to the type information that describes the exposed object (i has no type info)
    dispInterface   //the IUnknown of the object that implements IDispatch for me
);
```

What i cannot figure out is how the Windows API implemention of `CreateStdDispatch` knows what methods to call on my object - especially since `CreateStdDispatch` doesn't know what object-oriented language i'm using, or its calling conventions.

How will `CreateStdDispatch` know

- what method to call for a given `dispid`?
- the calling convention of my language?
- how to handle exceptions from the language that my object oriented object is written in?

**Note**: i have no choice but to implement a `dispinterface`; i didn't define [the interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). i wish it was a simple early bound `IUnknown`, but it tisn't.

Comment: Don't you just derive from `TAutoIntfObject` or am I missing something?

Comment: If *those* are really your implementations of the other three methods, then you don't really have to implement `Invoke`, either, since no consumer will ever get far enough to call it anyway. The consumer will call `GetIDsOfNames` to find out the dispid of the method or property it wants to invoke, but you're going to respond that it's not implemented. Without a dispid, the consumer cannot fill in the first `Invoke` parameter. Besides, the documentation doesn't say that `E_NOTIMPL` is even a valid result of `GetIDsOfNames`.

Comment: And why is this tagged as "delphi" if there isn't anything about delphi in the question? Delphi is never mentioned and all code shown is C.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: Not true. It's a dispinterface, and the person calling me (Internet Explorer) already knows the `dispIDs` it wants to invoke. See Techvanguard's excellent examples of automation event sinking (http://www.techvanguards.com/products/eventsinkimp/).

Comment: @Thorsten Engler: i changed the code examples to have a Delphi flair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to your question is: neither `CreateStdDispatch()` nor the `IDispatch` implementation it creates knows *anything at all* about the methods to be called.

The object that you get back simply stores the parameters that you passed to `CreateStdDispatch()`, and for all `IDispatch` methods it only turns around and makes the corresponding calls on the `ITypeInfo` that you gave it. That is all.

If you pass nil for `ptinfo` as shown in your code then you only get `E_INVALIDARG`, since the implementing object cannot do anything at all without an `ITypeInfo` to which to delegate all the work.

If you inspect the code for `CStdDisp` in oleaut32.dll then you will find that it calls API functions like `DispInvoke()` (which also live in that DLL) instead of invoking the `ITypeInfo` methods directly, but these functions are all simple wrappers for calls to the `ITypeInfo` methods, without any further functionality.

In case anyone wonders: neither `CreateStdDispatch()` nor `CStdDisp` performs any additional magic; all they do is give you an `IDispatch` that does whatever the `ITypeInfo` that you passed in can do. Think of it as a kind of an adapter that allows you to plug an `ITypeInfo` into an `IDispatch` socket.

It is true that `TAutoIntfObject.Create()` needs a type library. However, all that the constructor does is call `GetTypeInfoOfGuid()` on it in order to get a type info pointer, to which the object then delegates most of the work related to dispatch things.

Borland in their wisdom made the member variable for the type info pointer `private`, which means that you really need to hand the constructor some type library or other that contains the interface in question, instead of simply writing another constructor or overriding some virtual function. On the other hand it shouldn't be too hard to load the type library via the registry or to dump parts of it to a TLB file. Inspecting a TLB with OleView gives you actual compilable IDL which is often also Borland-compilable RIDL.

`CreateStdDispatch()` does not know anything about exceptions either. The catching of exceptions thrown from COM methods and their conversion to HRESULT and/or `IErrorInfo` is compiler magic induced by Delphi's `safecall` keyword on the implementing method.

The same goes for the translation of HRESULTs to exceptions when calling COM methods specified as safecall in their interface declarations. The compiler simply inserts a call to `@CheckAutoResult` after every invocation of a safecall method; this function checks the HRESULT and throws `EOleSysError` if appropriate.

Simply switch the Delphi debugger to disassembly ('CPU view') to inspect all the magic that the compiler does for you!

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't the `ITypeInfo` parameter passed into `CreateStdDispatch` expose all of the method information?

So you'd create type info first calling `CreateDispTypeInfo` and pass that through to `CreateStdDispatch` which can then use the type information to work out which method to call since `CreateDispTypeInfo` requires `INTERFACEDATA` which contains all this information

I could be way wrong since I don't have time to look into it but that would make sense to me. 
I'll investigate this later and update the answer.

Comment: This is exactly it. Ian, CreateStdDispatch knows all that stuff about your object because you *told* it that information when you gave it an ITypeInfo object. If you didn't give it one, then you're not finished with your project yet.

Comment: @Ian Why are you trying to write your own implementation of `IDispatch` when Delphi comes with one?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Where is Delphi's implementation of `IDispatch`?

Comment: Just derive from `TAutoIntfObject` like I said in comment to Q. I've never done it myself but that's my understanding of how it should be done. I think it's the way to go but I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are shooting at.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: i see it now, `ITypeInfo::AddressOfMember`, where i return the address of my class's methods. And although i don't know how to get the address of a class method, it certainly answers my question, "How does CreateStdDispatch" know how to call my methods?"  The answer is that i give it the addresses of the functions (presumably relative to the start of the object).

Comment: @David Heffernan: i am exposing the `DWebBrowserEvents2` interface on an existing object to sink events from Internet Explorer and the Windows Shell. Unfortunately `DWebBrowserEvents` is a dispinterface.

Comment: @Ian Doesn't `TAutoIntfObject` support dispinterfaces?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Yes it does. A dispinterface is an IDispatch-like interface, except that the ID's of the methods are known at compile time. As long as the object i'm exposing has an `IDispatch` interface, the caller can call `.Invoke`, passing the dispid and the method parameters.

Comment: @Ian Surely that's the answer to your problem, even if it's not the answer to the question you asked.

Comment: @David Hefernan: Problem with `TAutoIntfObject` is that it requires a type library, which i don't have. i already have code from VCL and from Techvanguards that i can copy-paste as my implementation of `IDispatch.Invoke`. But that wasn't my question; which was wondering how `CreateStdDispatch` could possibly know what methods to call on my object.